# Random Facebook Open Graph Debugger Error Messages?

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-graph-api

Some Time ago our users reported problems with sharing content from our page (text/image wouldn't show up in the share dialog), after some research we added the `og:image:width` and `og:image:height`-tags. To reduce loading time, the facebook-scraper receives the page with an empty `<body>` (we had troubles with timeout too).

Everything worked great until about a week ago. Pages that have already been scraped showed errors in the [Object-Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/):

```
Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.
```

This error shows up nearly everytime i click `Show existing scrape information`, eventually it would go away (without re-scraping the page) but then following error shows up:

```
The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.
```

The [Sharing-Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) additionally shows following error:

```
The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was 
caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a 
property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being 
mismatched. Here are the input properties that were not seen in the parsed result: 
'fb:admins, og:type, og:description, og:title, og:site_name, og:image:url, og:image:width, 
og:image:height'
```

Sometimes it also says that our images are too big and couldnt be downloaded, but the image is shown in the preview. Sometimes it even goes as far as showing

```
Could not scrape URL because it has been blocked
```

What doesnt add up here is that if i click on `See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL` it shows me the source of our page with empty `<body>` and `<og:...>`-tags in the `<head>`

The debugger shows me the correct `og:url`, `og:type`, `og:title`, `og:description` and `og:image`, the preview is alright, response code is `206` and last scraping was somewhere in August.

After rescraping a few times, most of the time the error messages are gone, but that cant be the solution. It seems as if the debugger sends random errors for whatever reason

So what do these error messages really mean? Are they wrong? What am i missing here?

(Note: a 3rd pary is having trouble sharing our pages in their application due to those error messages, everytime they appeared in the debugger, their data seems to be somehow broken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some back and forth with one of facebooks supporter in the developer forum, they acknowledged my problem as a bug and assigned a team for further investigation. However, a few days later my bug report was closed with following message:

> Those messages are due to a bug in our Debugger when you scrape no-canonical URLs. On that case, the information about your URL is updated asynchronously so it takes a little while for the error messages to go away.
>
> If you input the canonical URL in the debugger, the error messages will go away after the first scrape.
>
> Unfortunately, due to the way our systems works, we are not planning to fix that error in the near future.